# Object not found XAMPP PHP error

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to run a php file using xampp but I'm getting the Object not found error, I watched some videos where people say create another folder and run it under that but that is not working for me! look at the screenshot below and please if you could help me understand why this isn't working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFmV8.jpg)

Please note even if i use another file such as footer.php i get the same error.

here is the code for mens.php i didnt include it in the screenshot

```
<?php
session_start();
//unset($_SESSION['basket']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- External Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Mens</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bar">Sale Now On!</div>

<div id="outer">

<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<!-- All content will be wrapped insisde this container -->
<div id="container">
    <!-- Page -->
    <h2>Mens Clothing</h2>



    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="headings">
            <th style="width: 20%;">Photo</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;">Desciption</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Size</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Price</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Qty</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Action</th>

        </tr>
        <form action="addtocart.php" method="post" name="addtocart">
        <tr class="datarow">
            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border-left:dotted 
 1px #333; border-bottom: dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <img src="img/suit.jpg" width="112px" />
            </td>


            <td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;  border-bottom: 
dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">Contempary Hugo Boss 
Suit</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="Contempary Hugo Boss 
 Suit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pic" value="suit.jpg" />


            <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <select name="size">
                    <option value="S">Small</option>
                    <option value="M">Medium</option>
                    <option value="L">Large</option>
                </select>

            </td>

            <td  style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: 
dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">&pound;500.00</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="500.00" />


            <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <select name="qty">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>                   
            </td>


            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Basket" />

            </td>

        </tr>
        </form>

        <form action="addtocart.php" method="post" name="addtocart">

        <tr class="datarow">
            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border-left:dotted 
 1px #333; border-bottom: dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <img src="img/suit1.jpg" width="112px" />
            </td>


            <td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;  border-bottom: 
dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">Wool Hugo Boss Suit</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="Wool Hugo Boss Suit" 
/>
            <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="101" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pic" value="suit1.jpg" />


            <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <select name="size">
                    <option value="S">Small</option>
                    <option value="M">Medium</option>
                    <option value="L">Large</option>
                </select>

            </td>

            <td  style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: 
dotted 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">&pound;450.00</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="450.00" />


            <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">
                <select name="qty">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>                   
            </td>


            <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border-bottom: dotted 
 1px #333; border-right:dotted 1px #333;">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Basket" />

            </td>

        </tr>
        </form>

    </table>






</div>

</div>

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of trying `localhost` how about trying `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/example/footer.php it says site cant be reached

Comment: Why did you put port 5000?

Comment: sorry, put that by mistake, still says object not found!

Comment: You should add your code here instead of linking to an image of it. It makes it easier for us to debug.

Comment: added the code..

Answer (score 1):

A file called `._mens.php` Is NOT the same as a file called `mens.php`

As you are using the url `localhost/example/mens.php` then the file needs to be called `mens.php`

Comment: Yeah, I realised that so instead i wrote footer.php but i got the same error.